# git svn clone prints hundreds of "error: too many matches for svn-remote.svn.added-placeholder"

Tags: git, git-svn

I ran the following command to clone an SVN repository:

```
git svn clone -s --preserve-empty-dirs --username=my_svn_username https://svn.repo/path projectname
```

This ran successfully for a few hours, but is now printing the following message many, many times per revision:

```
error: too many matches for svn-remote.svn.added-placeholder
```

The clone process appears to continue; I can see revisions appear in the logs between these messages.  However, the number of times this error is printed seems to be increasing.  The first problematic revision resulted in the error being printed 39 times; the next 78; then 117 - the latest revision at time of writing caused the above error to be printed 13,604 times.

I'm cloning this repository from scratch because the existing repository from which I have been working successfully for many months has also encountered this error.  Everything was fine until I performed a `git svn fetch` which I believe caused git svn to discover a new branch which prompted this error.

I am able to checkout the first revision that displayed this error without problem when using SVN, and can update revision-by-revision successfully.

Has anyone seen this before?  Any clues to resolving the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved problem this morning.

There is definition #define MAX_MATCHES 512 in config.c which limits empty directories to 512.

Change it to something larger and use "make" and "make install" commands to compile and install git again to the computer.

Code can be seen in:
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/config.c

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction although I've no appetite at all to modify or compile git.  It turned out my .git/config file had ~6000 entries like **added-placeholder = path/to/.gitignore** - many duplicates per file, but only about 20 unique lines per branch.  In the end I solved it by untracking several SVN branches I didn't care about, and cleaning up the .git/config file.  I've no idea how the file got such bad data, so it may happen again, but this is definitely good enough for now.